# How does Auto ISO work on Nikon DSLRs in Manual mode with an on-camera flash?

Tags: nikon, flash, auto-iso

Nikon D7200.
Godox V860IIN.

This is part of what I know so far:

- Shutter speed is for controlling ambient light.
- Aperture is for controlling flash.
- ISO is for controlling overall light hitting the sensor.

How does exposure compensation work with it?

How does flash compensation work with it?

Comment: Related: [How can I get started with a first flash gun?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30740)

Comment: FYI, ambient exposure is controlled by iso, aperture, and shutter speed. But flash exposure is controlled by iso, aperture, flash power, and flash-to-subject distance. So, ISO *and* aperture **both** control ambient and flash. Your independent controls are really shutter speed for ambient, and flash power for flash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exposure Compensation adjusts exposure of the camera auto modes, like A, S, P, and Auto modes.  It does Not change camera Manual mode exposure, however, it does still affect what the light meter reads and shows, perhaps guiding you to adjust manual exposure yourself.

Flash Compensation adjusts metered TTL flash exposure.  It does not affect manual flash.  Manual is manual.

Auto ISO does affect camera exposure, including camera Manual mode exposure, and does affect TTL flash metering.  Manual flash cannot react to Auto ISO changing, and Auto ISO will stay at Minimum ISO if camera recognizes a manual flash is present.

There may be multiple places flash compensation can be specified (on flash or on camera for example, or in Commander menu if used), and they all add to a total.

On Nikons, Exposure Compensation also adds to Flash Compensation so that TTL flash reacts with the sum total.  However, newer models, including D7200, has a new E4 menu to either do that add (EC + FC), or not.   Canon models for example, do not.  Pros and cons either way.  Your choice.

Comment: Thanks WayneF. After setting my Aperture and Shutter Speed, I usually just adjust Exposure Compensation. Then I adjust Flash Compensation if needed.

Comment: In my experience, enabling Auto ISO with TTL flash will cause the camera to adjust ISO for what would be a proper exposure (or as close as it can get) _without_ the flash, and then also adjust the flash power so as to properly expose the subject at the resulting ISO. In other words, the camera will try to create a proper exposure for the background while not overexposing the foreground subject.